# Jquery dialog chrome issue - scroll not visible when opening for second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, iframe

This is my modal div element:

```
<div id="modal-window" style="display:none;">
    <iframe id="modal-window-inner-html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

And this is my jquery modal defined in javascript:

```
 $("#modal-window").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 350, 
        height: 800
 });
```

This is iframe css:

```
#modal-window iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

In iframe content I usually put large html that should scroll. I have one chrome issue (other browsers work fine), when I open modal for first time in chrome everything is fine (scroll is visible), but when I close modal and open again for second, third time etc. scroll is not visible but I can still scroll content. How to force this scroll to be visible?
I tried with putting overflow-y: auto !important; on iframe, putting maxHeight on jquery modal, destroying jquery modal on close, but nothing resolved the issue.

Comment: Try adding overflow-y: scroll !important

Comment: also, z-index might be an issue here as well. try adding a z-index as a really high number like 999 for e.g

Comment: First suggestion I already tried, and it's not solution. Where to put high z-index? Putting it on iframe didn't help.

Comment: Does the iframe need to fit the whole screen of the window? If not then try adding a fixed height in pixels.

Comment: Putting fixed height in pixels solved the issue. Thanks. You can write this as an answer.

Comment: And so how do you open modal?  You have to provide a MCVE, maybe replicate issue on jsFiddle

Comment: @bambi can you upvote it please. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Adding a fixed pixel height to iFrame should fix it

Comment: Changing height from 100% to fixed height in pixels cut off iframe content, since it has variable height, and I cannot definitely say how long content will be.

Comment: try adding min-height in pixels and the height as auto